# How to soak and sprout hazelnuts?

Tags: germination, sprouting

I have a few hazelnuts. How do I germinate them? What should I pay attention to? I would appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelnuts require a long spell in cold conditions over winter to germinate.

If your climate is suitable the easiest way is to plant them straight into the ground outdoors, but ideally you should have done that two or three months ago. Otherwise, you can keep them in your fridge for several months and then use artificial heat to kick-start them into germinating.

See [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/grow-hazelnuts-seeds-49350.html) for detailed instructions, but unless you *know* these are fresh seed harvested at the right time, prepare to be disappointed after a lot of effort and a long wait.